# How to join two arrays in C# using a single line of code

Tags: c#, linq

I have c# code:

```
string[] names = new [] { "a", "b", "c" };
int[] vals = new[] { 5, 10, 15 };
r = "";
for( int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++ )
r += names[i] + ": " + vals[i] + " ";
```

In python I can write oneliner

```
r = " ".join( [ names[i] + ":" + str(vals[i]) for i in range(len(names)) ] )
```

How can i do this in c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a *slightly* different approach to the Python code - I'd use the [LINQ "zip" operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) to produce a sequence of strings you want to join together, then use `string.Join` to join them:

```cs
string result = string.Join(" ", names.Zip(values, (n, v) => $"{n}:{v}");
```

So within that:

- The `names.Zip(values, <something>)` part produces a sequence of values based on applying the "something" to each pair of values from `names` and `values`.
- The `(n, v) => $"{n}:{v}"` part takes a name and a value, and formats them as name:value.
- The `string.Join(" ", <sequence>)` part joins the sequence elements together with a space between each pair of values.

Note that this *doesn't* end up with a trailing space, unlike the original C# code.